# Understanding chroot

Tags: php, linux, docker, uwsgi, chroot

I'm running user apps in docker containers and everything was okay until I decided to use supervisorctl so that I could remotely start/stop the apps via rpc. Now I need a way to prevent the user's app from introspecting the container, discovering the supervisord.conf & logs and/or executing the supervisord/supervisorctl bins.

The way to do this would be to use chroot, but I'm unclear as to how to do this.

Reading uwsgi's documentation all one needs to do is run

```
mkdir -p /ns/001
debootstrap maverick /ns/001
chroot /ns/001
# in the chroot jail now
adduser uwsgi
apt-get install mercurial python-flask
su - uwsgi
# as uwsgi now
git clone https://github.com/unbit/uwsgicc.git .
exit # out of su - uwsgi
exit # out of the jail
Now on your real system run

uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:3031 --chdir /home/uwsgi/uwsgi --uid uwsgi --gid uwsgi --module uwsgicc --master --processes 4 --namespace /ns/001:mybeautifulhostname
```

To get uwsgi to run in a chroot container.

PHP-FPM also seems to have a similar config option where you have to set

```
prefix = /var/www/example.com
chroot = $prefix
chdir = /
listen = tmp/php5-fpm.sock
slowlog = log/$pool.log.slow
```

I'm uncertain as to the need to run debootstrap within a container. Also I don't understand how in the uwsgi example; they run the uwsgi bin outside the chroot, wouldn't you need to install uwsgi inside the chroot and then have something like /ns/001/usr/bin/uwsgi in your supervisord.conf outside the chroot?

I can't seem to find a single standard way to run a chroot and atm so I'm considering running a setup similar to

```
RUN set -e;
    apk add --no-cache supervisor;
    mkdir -p /ns/001;
    debootstrap alpine /ns/001;
    chroot /ns/001;
    # in the chroot jail now
    # install all my packages here, all the stuff that was in the container apk add --no-cache everything
    before gets moved here
    # exit the chroot
    in my superisord.conf then just specify /ns/001/path/to/bins/in/chroot
```

Would the above be a viable approach?

I think I've also seen examples that only use the `chdir` option for php-fpm and uwsgi, is this some way to avoid having to setup the chroot environment? And very simple preventing a process eg. python from seeing beyond the chroot dir?

Would a chroot also limit the env variables seen by that process?